# How to make MacOS Catalina to receive incoming X connections (without ssh tunnels)

Tags: catalina, xquartz

I am trying to make my MacOS Catalina to receive incoming X conncetions. I have installed `XQuartz`, then I have issued `xhost +`. Then on my linux box I set `export DISPLAY=my.macos.ip.address:0.0`.

But unfortunately, when I ran on my Linux box I get

```
xcalc &                        
[1] 3534
Error: Can't open display: my.macos.ip.address:0.0                                     
➜  ~ 
[1]  + 3534 exit 1     xcalc
```

How to fix? What else can be done?

Don't suggest to make ssh tunnel please.

Comment: Start XQuartz first?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that XQuartz is started before attempting to run `xcalc`.

When XQuartz is started, you can run this command in the `xterm` that appears:

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

It should let you know which display number you're using. Make sure to use the same display number after the `:` on the Linux side.

In addition you'll want to ensure that you haven't firewalled the incoming ports (6000, 6001, etc. depending on your display number) on the Mac computer. For example if you're using a tool like Little Snitch or similar, you should ensure that you haven't setup anything there to block this traffic.